# Create modal window like Google Keep for web

Tags: javascript, ember.js, modal-dialog, ember-cli, google-keep

I'm using Ember for a project and I would change some test in a list just like the modals on Google Keep web version.

How to recreate the modal windows that appear when I click an item?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in the [Ember Cookbook: Using Modal Dialogs](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/).